# Should I Have two repos, one for the source code and one for the build

Tags: git, version-control

When deploying a web app for instance in Angular, is it best to create a repository for the the main angular source code and another for the dist after ng build. That way when deploying, you can easily do so by cloning your dist repository and can easily make changes to that by re-commiting on any other build?

Comment: Git isn't really a deployment tool at all. Keep the repository for the source, but use a proper deployment tool for the build.

Comment: Ok, what tool can i use for the build please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you don't want to store build products in a repository, even in a separate repository for that purpose.  That's because Git keeps the history of every object, and that means your repository is almost certainly going grow to a huge size.

There are a lot of standalone deployment tools that exist.  Capistrano is one such tool, but there are other options as well.  Usually these will take some generated artifact, such as a tarball, and deploy it to the appropriate set of systems.